# get the operating system of an Amazon image via Fog

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

My end goal is to get the operating system of an Amazon image. When I do:

```
connection = Fog::Compute.new(provider: 'AWS',
                              aws_access_key_id: 'blah',
                              aws_secret_access_key: 'thing')
images = connection.describe_images('Owner' => 'self').body['imagesSet']
```

The data I get returned does not include `platform`, as [this documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/fog/fog/Fog/Compute/AWS/Real%3adescribe_images) suggests. However, I do get values like:

```
architecture: "x86_64",
imageType: "machine",
kernelId: "aki-825ea7eb",
```

And if I Google for that kernel ID I find [this page](http://thecloudmarket.com/image/aki-825ea7eb#/definition) saying it's Linux. Is there a way I can pass `kernelId` to Amazon via Fog and get back data about that `kernelId`, such as `linux`?

On a separate note, sometimes my images don't have `kernelId`, so are there any other fields in a `<DescribeImagesResponse xmlns="http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-12-01/">` that are definite indicators of operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you have the Kernel ID using http://thecloudmarket.com.

Pass the Kernel ID to a variable in ruby.

```
    ker_id = imagesSet

    url = []
    url_0 = "http://thecloudmarket.com/image/"
    url_1 = "ker_id"
    url_2 = "#/definition"

    new_url = url_0 + url_1 _ url_2
```

There are many ways to forge this url just made it easy to read.

Then use nokogiri to parse the webpage and put the image name back into your script. 
I didn't see another notifiers in the documentation.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a cleaner way, preferably a service on Amazon itself or even an external API, like an API from thecloudmarket.com.